# IE "Enhanced Protected Mode (122)": What is the meaning of the "122"?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am developing a Browser Helper Object (BHO) for Internet Explorer written in C#. I use the BeforeNavigate event to get a called URL and save it into a local variable. For every tab a new BHO instance is spawned. This means that every tab has it's own BHO which in turn have own local variables. I have checked this by displaying a MessageBox with the previous called URL (the value of the local variable) before it is overwritten with the new URL.

```
string myUrl = "";

void BeforeNavigate( string URL, ... )
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( myUrl );
    myUrl = URL.ToString();
}
```

But in some cases the local variable is empty although a URL was called before. I investigated the IE settings and found out that this behavior is caused by the zone elevation protection of IE. For the zones local intranet and trusted sites the protected mode is disabled while it is enabled for zones internet and restricted sites.

E.g., when intranet.com is called and then internet.com in the same tab, I would expect that the MessageBox displays intranet.com when internet.com is called. But an empty string is displayed instead. I guess that calling internet.com activates the protected mode for this tab which spawns a new instance of the BHO. The MessageBox will now display the value of the variable of the new BHO instance. The value of the variable of the old BHO gets lost.

If protected mode is enabled for zones local intranet and trusted sites the BHO behaves correctly.

This issue I already described in [IE's zone elevation protection interferences functionality of BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777207) to this point.

When I enable the EPM (Enhanced Protected Mode) the same problem occurs even if protected mode is enabled in all zones. Strangely also if I explicitly remove the tested URLs from the zones `local intranet` and `trusted sites`. (Note that "protected mode" and "enhanced protected mode" are different.)

In the context menu of a website the menu item `properties` gives information about the mode in which a website is executed. For websites in the internet the mode `Internet | Protected Mode: Enhanced` is displayed indicating that this website is executed in EPM.

I discovered that websites that belong to the intranet are executed in a "special" EPM. For an intranet website the mode `Local Intranet | Protected Mode: Enhanced (122)` is displayed. After I removed the tested URLs from the zones, `Internet | Protected Mode: Enhanced (122)` is displayed. I tried to find out what the `122` means but could not find any helpful information. It seems that calling a `Internet | Protected Mode: Enhanced (122)` website and then a `Internet | Protected Mode: Enhanced` website in the same tab triggers a boundary crossing which leads to the same issue.

Can anyone provide information about the meaning of the `122`?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A BHO is a DLL. All global variables in a DLL are specific to the process in which the DLL is loaded. If you want to share a common global value across all instances of `iexplore.exe`, you will have to be creative, especially as when running in some protected mode the set of Win32 APIs you can use the escape the sandbox is pretty restricted.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is just an inner serial number.

For more information about Enhanced Protected Mode, see the following Internet Explorer blog articles:

[Enhanced Protected Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/03/14/enhanced-protected-mode/)

[Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/)

Comment: I've already read several articles, also the ones you mentioned. I want to know how I can solve the issue or at least what the reason is.